# Автоувеличение id в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Таблица содержит два столбца:

```
id | description
```

Как сделать так, что при добавлении новой строки id пользователя будет наращиваться сам? То есть

```
INSERT INTO users DEFAULT VALUES;
```

даст (1, ), (2, ) и тд.

Answer (score 13):

Надо сделать id типом [serial или big serial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html):

> `serial    4 bytes autoincrementing integer       1 to 2147483647
> bigserial 8 bytes large autoincrementing integer 1 to 9223372036854775807`

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id          SERIAL,
    description TEXT
);
```

Answer (score 9):

Дополню ответ [@John Brown](/users/9/john-brown), так как типы `SERIAL` и `BIGSERIAL` появились в Postgres не так давно.

Еще один способ создать автоинкрементное поле заключается в том, чтобы связать его с последовательностью (SEQUENCE), наподобие того, как это делается в Оракле:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq;

ALTER TABLE table 
    ALTER COLUMN id 
        SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('table_id_seq');
```

Answer (score 8):

Начиная с PostgreSQL 10 был реализован синтаксис создания автоматически генерируемых последовательностей соответствующий современным стандартам SQL.

```
сreate table foo (
    id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Этот синтаксис является стандартом, и такой запрос будет переносим между, например, PostgreSQL, DB2, Oracle.

Если чуть углубиться внутрь - этот синтаксис `postgresql` опирается на уже давно существующие  свои [`sequence`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html). Так, этим запросом был неявно создан новый `sequence` и дополнительно привязан к полю таблицы, так чтобы его не получилось случайно удалить.

Упомянутые в других ответах `smallserial`, `serial` и `bigserial` - это тоже ненастоящие типы данных и как таковых их не существует. Например, вы не сможете привести другой тип данных к serial. Это простой синтаксический сахар вокруг создания `sequence` и назначения `default` для поля. Так, таблица вида

```
create table foo (id serial);
```

[На самом деле является](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/parser/parse_utilcmd.c#L582) эквивалентом для:

```
CREATE TABLE public.foo (
  id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE public.foo_id_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.foo_id_seq OWNED BY public.foo.id;

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.foo ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.foo_id_seq'::regclass);
```

И именно так его видно через `pg_dump`, например.

---

Поэтому фактически ответ: если вы хотите автоматически генерируемый счётчик в postgresql, безопасный для конкурентного доступа - вам нужны `sequence`. А способов его объявить, как это часто бывает в SQL, есть несколько разных.

Если версия базы позволяет, наверное будет лучше уже использовать стандартный SQL синтаксис `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 0):

завести последовательность и повесить тригер на вставку (на предвставку)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE схема.таблица_id_seq MINVALUE=0 NO MAXVALUE CYCLE;
ALTER TABLE схема.таблица 
ALTER COLUMN id 
SET DEFAULT nextval('схема.таблица_id_seq');
ALTER SEQUENCE схема.таблица_id_seq OWNED BY схема.таблица_id_seq;
```