# Случайный уникальный ID в PosgreSQL с помощью asyncpg

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, asyncpg

Вопрос по работе с **PostgreSQL** в **Python** с помощью **AsyncPG**.
Задача следующая:
Необходимо в таблицу добавить новую строку с генерацией случайного ID (целые числа) для неё и внесением в неё записей для нескольких столбцов, а после внесения записей получить ID этой строки в таблице в рамках одного метода **Python**.

Можно конечно получить ID этой строки через соответствие других столбцов, но может есть более простой вариант?

Примерная логика данной задачи:

*Вызывается метод Python c запросом к БД для добавления новой записи с определенными данными. В процессе добавления записи, генерируется уникальный ID для этой строки. После добавления записи нужно получить значение этого ID.*

В программировании и работе с БД новичок. На текущий момент работа с БД настроена с помощью **asyncpg.create_pool**.

**Решение найдено:**

```py
async def new_row(data1, data2):  
    async with connection.acquire() as con:  
        result = await con.fetchrow('''INSERT INTO table (column2, column3) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id''', data1, data2)  
    await con.close()
    return result[0]
```

`id` - это `column1` в таблице: `id smallserial PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автоувеличение id в PostgreSQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32938/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-id-%d0%b2-postgresql)